# Why does a certain turing machine only accept regular languages?

Tags: regular-language, turing-machines

why does a single tape turing machine, which can not write on the part of its tape containing the input, only accept regular languages?

I am asking this because this question is being opposed to me in an assignment.

Comment: A TM has a read-write tape and a finite control.  A finite automaton has a read-only input and a finite control.  If you take away the TM's ability to write to the tape, it becomes a finite automaton.

Comment: That's a good point which is certainly useful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is in fact harder than what the MJD's comment make it look like.

In fact a TM with read only tape is a two way automaton (since TM can go back on the tape, as 2 ways automaton).

It turns out however that 2 way automaton accept regular languages but this is not trivial (see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_finite_automaton).